# nginx ssl_dhparam key for each vhost, or once for entire configuration? vs SSL confg

Tags: nginx

Should diffie hellman parameters (`ssl_dhparam` key) be generated for each vhost, or just placed within `http{...}`? (for completely different website served up by the same host.

Conversely, to confirm, `ssl_certificate`, `ssl_certificate_key`, `ssl_trusted_certificate` should be different for each website?
Is there a way to refer to these three parameters if used in multiple vhosts (e.g. forwarding none www to www) without copy pasting? (Trying to follow the DRY principle, one source of truth)

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the parameter at all.

Doing so [enables](https://nginx.org/r/ssl_dhparam) DHE ciphers, which have been [deprecated](https://www.digicert.com/blog/google-plans-to-deprecate-dhe-cipher-suites/), and which are recommended to be [disabled](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/security-dev/dYyhKHPnrI0) in favor of ECDHE ciphers.